# About extended of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Assume we have an open interval $I\subset\Bbb R$ and a set $D\subset I.$ Let $f\colon D\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous such that $f$ can not be extended to a continuous on $I.$ What we can conclude from that ?

Comment: What kinds of possible conclusions are you interested in?

Comment: @GregMartin, Thank you. I am interested in something to find an open interval $J\subset I$ and $x_J\in J$ such that $\text{lim sup}$ and $\text{lim inf}$ when $x\in D$ approaches   $x_J$ will be different

Comment: @00GB: If $f$ cannot be extended to a continuous function on $I$, there must be an $x\in I\cap\operatorname{cl}D$ at which the [oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)) of $f$ is positive; this appears to be exactly what you want.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thank you. I just checked the definition for oscillation and I found if $f$ is continuous at x iff the oscillation at this point would be zero. So, I can see why you positive  but    $f$  is not define at $x$ that you mentioned in you comment since $f$ is defined only on $D$

Comment: @00GB: That doesn’t matter: the oscillation of $f$ at $x$ is independent of $f(x)$ and is defined in a way that does not even require $f(x)$ to be defined. It’s perfectly true that if $f$ has no continuous extension on $I$, then $D$ is not closed, but that’s trivial; the existence of a point in $\operatorname{cl}D$ where the oscillation is non-zero is the precise equivalent.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I still did not see how we can conclude that there exists an open interval $J\subset I$  and  $x_J$ such that $\text{lim sup }$ and $\text{lim inf }$  when $x\in D$ approaches $x_J$ will be different. Since $f$ is not bounded so I can not write oscillation as difference between $\text{sup}$ and $\text{inf}$

Comment: @00GB: The oscillation **is** $\limsup-\liminf$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, could you please write the full definition so I got confused. I found some thing different. OR refer me to reference. Thank you in advance

Comment: @00GB: Everything that you need is at the Wikipedia link that I posted earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{ Claim:}$ The set $ D $ is not close in $ I $.

To see this we proceed by contradiction, in particular we will show that if $ D $ is close then there exists an extension. Suppose $ D $ close and non-empty. Let $ a = \min\{ x \in D \} $ and $ d = \max \{ x \in D \} $. We extend $ f $ in $ \mathbb{R} \setminus [a,b]  $ by setting $ \tilde{f}(x) = f(a) $ for $ x < a $ and  $ \tilde{f}(x) = f(b) $ for $ x > b $. Let $ x \in (a,b) $, we define $ y_-(x) = \sup\{ y \in D $ such that $ y < x \} $ and $ y_+(x) = \inf\{ y \in D $ such that $ y > x \} $. Define
$$ \tilde{f}(x) = f(y_{-}(x)) + \frac{x-y_{-}(x)}{y_{+}(x)-y_{-}(x)}(f(y_{+}(x))-f(y_{-}(x))).$$
The function $ \tilde{f} $ is a continuous extension of $ f $.

$ \textbf{Consequences:} $ if $ f$ cannot be extended to $ I $ then $ f $ cannot be extended to the closure of $ D $ that we denoted $ \bar{D} $.

One can wonder why one cannot extend $ f $ to $ \bar{D} $ and this happens if and only if there exists $ x \in \bar{D} \setminus D $ and a sequence $ x_{n} $ that converge to $ x $ such that $ f(x_{n}) $ does not converge.

$ \textbf{ Some examples:} $

- $ f(x_{n}) $ diverge to $ \infty $ (imagine 1/x around zero)
- $ f(x_{n}) $ does not converge (imagine a function that oscillate a lot like $sin(1/x)$ close to zero)
- $ f(x_{n}) $ converge from the ''left and the right''  but the limit is different (imagine sing(x) around zero)

Comment: Justification or a reference would improve this answer.

Comment: user318989, I am interested in other reason, see my pervious comment for @GregMartin

Comment: user318989, Thank you for answer, Did you assume $D$ bounded in your answer ?

Comment: user318989, One more  question , could you please say some words how you came up with the definition of $\tilde f$ on $\Bbb R \setminus [a,b]$

Comment: It is not necessary to assume $ D $ bounded. You can imagine to allow the case $ a $ or $ b $ to be $ \pm \infty $. In $ \mathbb{R} \setminus [a,+\infty] $ I extend the function to be a constant equal to the value in $ a $, i.e. $ f(a) $. But you can do what you prefer